# How to create one logfile when ssh-ing to multiple servers

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, mount, logfile

I'd like to create a bash script to automatically connect myself to a bunch of servers, execute some commands there and save the output of these commands in **one** logfile on the server I use to connect myself to all the other servers.

So far I was able to create a logfile on each of the servers I'm connecting myself to or to display the output of each of the commands on the console of the server I use to get to all the other servers.

My script currently looks like this (I know about for loops, but I don't want to use them in this case because I need to execute different commands on each server):

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh server1 <<EOF
hostname
printf '\n'
mount
EOF 

printf '\n'
printf '\n'
printf '\n'

ssh server2 <<EOF
hostname
printf '\n'
mount
EOF

...
```

My idea was to use the `&>>` operator, because I need to know if all commands where executed successfully or not. In the end I'd like to have only one logfile which should look somewhat like this:

```
server1

output of mount 



server 2 

output of mount 

...
```

So, how can I manage to create only one large logfile that contains the results of all executed commands? Also, will this script still work correctly if I make use of the ssh -T option to get rid of the message "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."? And do I have to escape special characters like / _ - when using mount in my script to mount something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can redirect the output of the entire script, or group a redirection with `{command; othercommand; etc} >logfile` where the semicolon is syntactically equivalent to a newline.

Comment: Your tangential follow-up questions seem unrelated to this and should probably be removed. Only one question per question, please.

Comment: Like this? 

./myscript &>> mylogfile

Comment: You should generally avoid code duplication. Your script looks like you have not yet discovered the loop...?

Comment: Yeah, except that will append, and the `&` is Bash only; I tend to prefer the portable redirect `command >log 2>&1`

Comment: Thank you very much! I'd normally use a loop, but the problem here is that I need to mount different things on each server so I didn't use it for this task. The script shown above was my first approach to test if the ssh-ing and simple commands work.

Comment: Loop over pairs of values: servers and for each server, what to mount.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Open source utilities like [logstash](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/read-log-files-from-remote-location-in-linux/79935) or [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/guides/recipes/rsyslogd-aggregation).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/), which is a tool to interact with several servers using ssh. It provides operations for executing remote shell commands.

For your example, the **fabfile**:

```
from fabric.api import run, sudo

def my-task():
    run('hostname')
    run('mount')
```

An you can execute it:

```
fab -H server1,server2 my-task
```

Output will be via standard output of the server you are executing so you can easily redirect it to a file:

```
fab -H server1,server2 my-task | my-task.log
```